# Bootstrap requires popper.js despite bundle when used in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I installed `bootstrap@next` (`v5.0.0-alpha1`) through `npm`. i added the bundle JS to the scripts, but after compiling I receive this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'popper.js' in
'./foo/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js'
```

The [README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap?activeTab=versions) clearly states (**bold text**):

> We provide compiled CSS and JS (bootstrap.*), as well as compiled and minified CSS and JS (bootstrap.min.*). source maps (bootstrap.*.map) are available for use with certain browsers' developer tools. **Bundled JS files (bootstrap.bundle.js and minified bootstrap.bundle.min.js) include Popper.**

**angular.json**

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js",
],
```

Any idea what I could miss here?

Comment: it seems you are trying to import bootstrap somewhere in your app, except for angular.json. remove it and it should work fine

Answer (score 2):

It should be enough for the popper to be just listed in package.json. I had the same issue and upon deleting "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js" it has worked for me.

Comment: Curious, why would I need to list it though since it's part of bootstrap.bundle.js? Or did I misunderstand?